# Return in Switch javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, return

hello everyone I'm new to programming and having a hard time figuring out `return` while practising on freecodecamp. Here is a case of using `return` in `switch` statement.

**Example**

```
function sequentialSizes(val) {
    var answer = ""; 
    // Only change > code below this line 
    switch (val) { 
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            return "Low";
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
            return "Mid"
            break;
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9:
            return "High";
            break;
    } 
    // Only change code above this line 
    return answer; 
}
// Change this value to test 
sequentialSizes(1);
```

What i am not understanding is that the `switch` statement is returning low mid and high for different cases and the function is returning the answer whose value is not defined earlier. But the code works, HOW? What is the logic? Is it because when we return the answer it takes the value returned by the `switch` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable answer is not used. The return statements inside the cases specify what the function will return given different conditions. The way the switch/case statement works is it takes a variable, in this case val, and evaluates the value. It finds the matching case, if there is one, if not it uses the default. Once it reaches the case it begins executing code. For example, if val=5, case 5 is triggered. The code begins executing until it hits a break statement at which points it exits from the switch case. If case 5 is triggered, we return "Mid" then break. The break in this scenario is actually not executed because we return from the function as soon as we hit the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

`return` doesn't return from a specific statement, it returns from the function. It can be used anywhere in the function, including `if` statements, `switch` statements, `for` and `while` loops, etc. The function ends immediately and its return value is the argument to the `return` statement (or `undefined` if there's no argument).

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to understand the basic concepts of return and switch. Lets try to understand return first.

```
function sequentialSizes(val) { 
  var answer = ""; 
  return answer;
}
```

This function is going to return the value of variable **answer** when you call the function.

Switch case is block which going execute when the input matches the case value.

So in this case If you trigger the function with **sequentialSizes(1)** it will match with case 1 and go inside that block but it will return undefined **answer** variable.

```
function sequentialSizes(val) { 
 var answer = ""; 

switch (val) { 
 case 1: case 2: case 3: 
 return answer;
 break; 

 case 4: case 5: case 6: 
  return answer;
 break; 

 case 7: case 8: case 9: 
 return answer;
 break; 
 }
}
```

so assign the value to **answer** variable and return that.